# Java - Function does not return what I expected

Tags: java, string, try-catch, equals

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String string1 = "randomString1";                       
    System.out.print(f(string1));
}

public static int f(String string)
{
    try { 
        String string2 = "randomString2";

        if(string.equals(string2) == true);
            return 0;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 1;
}

}//end of class
```

Now, the output of this program is

> 0

But I expected it to be:

> 1

Because what I wanted the `f` function to do was to return `0` if the strings were the same and `1` if they weren't.

So, there's definitely something I know wrong here, and I'm guessing it has something to do with the `equals` method.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: remove the `;` from `if (string.equals(string2) == true);` This is a perfect example why you should program defensively always using `{` and `}` like `if (string.equals(string2)) { return 0; }`

Comment: There is no possibility of an exception being thrown here. Why the try-catch progression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the problem:

```
if(string.equals(string2) == true);
----------------------------------^
```

you'll need remove the semi-colon else, it is pretty much an expression on its own doing nothing:

```
if(string.equals(string2) == true) return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

`if(string.equals(string2) == true);` you have a semicolon there which does not belong.
  Honestly you don't even need the `== true` part as well.

Answer (score 1):

because of the semi-colon in the end of your if :

```
if (string.equals(string2) == true);
//---------------------------------^
return 0;
```

So when you make a semi-colon in the end of if mean that a statement is end start a new statement which is `return 0` for that you get `0` and not `1`

to understand more, what did you have mean this :

```
if (string.equals(string2) == true){
   //do nothing
}
//pass to the next statement
return 0;
```

So instead you can use :

```
if (string.equals(string2)){
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

man...

```
if(string.equals(string2) == true);
```

The **semi-colon (;)** this prevents the code to go inside the if block, and hence the

```
return 0;
```

line executes and returns 0

The program works fine as it should.

The solution to your problem...

```
if(string.equals(string2))
    return 0;
```

Remove the semi-colon.. the code would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary semilocon at the end of your if statement. Try below option:

```
if(string.equals(string2)) {
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified.

```
public static int f(String string)
{
    String string2 = "randomString2";

    return (!TextUtils.isEmpty(string) && string.equals(string2)) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

No need of try-catch as TextUtils will handle null for string.